# The address is only partially matched via API, while is accurately found on Google Maps

Tags: google-geocoder

I am trying to geocode addresses using the google API. For some addresses, I get a partial match of postal_code and hence not the accurate coordinates, while I have provided the correct street and house number.
The same address is correctly geocoded on maps.google.com, hence the address cannot be the problem.

How can I get the exact match of addresses and not partial matches?

For example, the following address:
Weisthum 4, 83342 Tacherting, Germany

Here is the URL for geocoding:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Weisthum%204,%2083342%20Tacherting,%20Germany

Or using components:
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=route:Weisthum%204|postal_code:83342|locality:Tacherting|country:DE](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=route:Weisthum%204%7Cpostal_code:83342%7Clocality:Tacherting%7Ccountry:DE)

The address is partially matched with the type set to postal_code, i.e. the coordinates returned are related to the postal code: 48.087408, 12.496696 which are not correct for this address.

However, when I use maps.google.com, the correct address is accurately found and the coordinates are completely correct: 48.063657, 12.460286

Here is the URL for google maps search: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Weisthum+4,+83342+Tacherting/@48.0635281,12.4554582,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x4775e0728857039b:0xffe87c77ca2e94f5!8m2!3d48.0635282!4d12.4603291!16s%2Fg%2F11qyqn5k2j?entry=ttu